# Who is crawling my website?

Tags: security, web

This is the log of requests to my website:

```
Started GET "/car_washes/1804/requests/legal" for 198.27.82.153 at 2015-05-18 09:49:09 +0400
Processing by RequestsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"car_wash_id"=>"1804", "id"=>"legal"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 160ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Request with 'id'=legal):
  app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:89:in `set_request'


Started GET "/car_washes/1806/requests/legal" for 198.27.82.153 at 2015-05-18 09:49:12 +0400
Processing by RequestsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"car_wash_id"=>"1806", "id"=>"legal"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 159ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Request with 'id'=legal):
  app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:89:in `set_request'


Started GET "/car_washes/1807/requests/legal" for 198.27.82.153 at 2015-05-18 09:49:16 +0400
Processing by RequestsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"car_wash_id"=>"1807", "id"=>"legal"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 155ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Request with 'id'=legal):
  app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:89:in `set_request'


Started GET "/car_washes/1808/requests/legal" for 198.27.82.153 at 2015-05-18 09:49:19 +0400
Processing by RequestsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"car_wash_id"=>"1808", "id"=>"legal"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 160ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Request with 'id'=legal):
  app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:89:in `set_request'
```

There is no link to `requests/legal` on a car_wash page. The bot made it out itself. It scans every car wash for a couple of months with that same request. Who and why could do it?

What is the real reason behind this?

Comment: Who: `198.27.82.153`. Why: I don't know of a good telepathy package.

Answer (score 0):

Using an IP lookup tool would be your friend.  It looks like you have been hit by an IP out of Montreal Canada.

https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-whois-lookup/

Just drop the IP in there and have a look yourself.